# Must these short methods be synchronized in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

Consider following static helper

```
public class DbUtil {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DbUtil.class);

    public static void closeAll(ResultSet rs, Statement stmt, Connection conn) {
        close(rs);
        close(stmt);
        close(conn);
    }

    public static void close(Connection connection) {
        if (connection != null) {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(null, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void close(Statement statement) {
        if (statement != null) {
            try {
                statement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(null, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void close(ResultSet resultSet) {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(null, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void closeAny(Object o) {
        if(o == null) return;

        try {
            if (o instanceof Statement) {
                Statement stmt = (Statement) o;
                stmt.close();
            } else if(o instanceof Connection) {
                Connection conn = (Connection) o;
                conn.close();
            } else if(o instanceof ResultSet) {
                ResultSet rs = (ResultSet) o;
                rs.close();
            } else {
                logger.warn("Unknown object type");
            }
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            logger.error(null, e);
        }
    }

}
```

This class can be used by multiple thread. Must all its methods be synchronized or some of them and why?

Actually I'm not sure is it possible that after `resultSet != null` check by one thread formal parameter(s) are changed with different object instance(s) by another thread and thus another ResultSet, Statement or Connection is closed (in case the methods are not synchronized).

Comment: Where does the try statement belong to?

Comment: Woops, sorry, amended.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm not sure is it possible that after resultSet != null check by one thread formal parameter(s) are changed with different object instance(s) by another thread

No, method arguments have the same semantics as local variables. They are private to a single method invocation and cannot be mutated by any other thread.

If each of your calling threads uses objects from its own thread-local connection, then there are no issues. Your methods do not share any state in that case.

Comment: If the downvoter would care to share what is wrong with this answer, I may be able to improve it. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Marko, does this mean that all mentioned methods are thread-safe without "synchronized" modifier?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. The methods are completely stateless.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Java 7 you should use much easier code:

```
public class DbUtil {

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(DbUtil.class);

    public static void closeAll(AutoCloseable... resources) {
        for (AutoCloseable resource: resources)
            close(resource);
    }

    public static void close(AutoCloseable resource) {
        if (resource != null) {
            try {
                resource.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(null, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```